# Strings > 4000 to CLOB conversion using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, clob

i have a java class persisting a string (>4k) into a database table into a CLOB field.
If the string is less than 4k then it works.

I have the field annotated using @Lob and initially I was getting an exception due to batching not supported for streams so I made the batch size 0 in the Hibernate config which is giving the exception:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

```
  at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
  at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
  at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:582)
  at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1986)
  at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteFetch(TTC7Protocol.java:1144)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeNonQuery(OracleStatement.java:2152)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteOther(OracleStatement.java:2035)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2876)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:609)
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:23)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2062)
  ... 36 more
```

I only get this issue when using the code from Grails. When I use the same code from a pure Java application then I don't get the issue. Both applications have the same hibernate config (except I need to set the batch size to 0 in Grails). Is the issue the difference in the Hibernate versions which is 3.2.6ga in Grails as far as I can see and 3.2.5ga for the java application. The Oracle driver is the same in both cases.

Any answers welcome.

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try with annotating the field with `@Column(length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)`. This [hibernate bug report](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4316) mentions it helped in Derby.